# Installing Trac with Subversion

Tags: svn

i am installing trac with subversion while installing i have error, i am following this link "http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Ubuntu-11.04-Subversion"....when i give the database string it gives the following error , could anybody please help....??

```
Database connection string [sqlite:db/trac.db]> mysql://trac:yourpassword@localhost/trac

Creating and Initializing Project
Initenv for '/var/tracprojects/YourProject' failed. 
Failed to create environment.
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tracprojects/YourProject'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.7.egg/trac/admin/console.py", line 413, in do_initenv
    options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.7.egg/trac/env.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.create(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.7.egg/trac/env.py", line 382, in create
    os.mkdir(self.path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tracprojects/YourProject'
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `/var/tracprojects/YourProject` the directory name you passed to `trac-admin`?

According to the instructions on the page you posted, you are meant to create that directory before calling `trac-admin` (the two commands before hand create the directory and set its permissions).  The error you received would indicate that you haven't done so.