# Installing Trac with Subversion

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Trac with Subversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56425/installing-trac-with-subversion)

hey i am still installing ubuntu......and i have error at the end i am following this link "http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Ubuntu-11.04-Subversion"

almost at the end it says .............

- Finally, you must grant admin rights to the user you've just created:

  ```
  trac-admin /var/lib/trac/YourProject permission add admin TRAC_ADMIN
  ```

when i insert this command `trac-admin /var/lib/trac/YourProject permission add admin TRAC_ADMIN`
it gives the following error....

> IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'admin-TRAC_ADMIN' for key 'PRIMARY'")

can anybody help please ............

Comment: I don't know so I am not posting an answer, but I assume from the error that the permissions are already set and this command hasg either been run twice or not needed. If you assume this step was already done, does the rest of the installation complete? You may need to ask on Trac